# Convergence or divergence for $\int_1^\infty\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} dx$ using comparison test.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have this improper integral and I want to know if it is convergent or divergent. My guess is that I should use the comparison theorem, because I have tried to integrate it and I found it difficult.

My attempt:

$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} dx$

So I start by choosing the "dominating" part on the bottom and keeping the top as it is.

$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4}} dx$

I can now remove the square root on the bottom.

$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2} dx$

Cancel one x.

$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx$

Integrate.

$\ln{\lvert x\rvert}$ from 1 to $\infty$

$\ln{\lvert \infty \rvert} - \ln{\lvert 1 \rvert}$

This is divergent because $\ln{\lvert \infty \rvert}$ is $\infty$.

$\ln{\lvert \infty \rvert}$

Now we need to make sure that our original improper integral is greater than or equal to the simplified integral.

$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} dx \geq \int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx \geq 0$ ?

The integral boundaries are the same so we only care about the functions.

$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \geq \frac{1}{x} \geq 0$ ?

Since everything is positive, we can cross-multiply.

$ x^2 \geq \sqrt{x^4+1} \geq 0$ ?

$ x^2$ is not greater than or equal to $\sqrt{x^4+1}$

I'm not sure how I should continue from here. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: start over, $x^4   + 1 \leq  2 x^4 $    since $x \geq 1$   and so

Comment: Comparison is a good idea, but it's not *that* hard to find an antiderivative; you can let $t=x^2$ and use that (hopefully) known $\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})$ thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to find a function $f$ such that $\sqrt{x^4+1}\le f$, as you said, $f$ cannot be $x^2$, but what about $f=\sqrt{x^4+x^4}$ ?

Since $1\le x$, we have $\Rightarrow 1\le x^4\Rightarrow x^4+1\le x^4+x^4=2x^4$, therefore

$$\sqrt{x^4+1}\le \sqrt{2x^4}=\sqrt2~x^2$$

Now we can use comparison test:

$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} dx\ge \int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt2~x^2} dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx\to\infty$$

So the integral is divergent.